# Background image doesn't show in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my site http://aspspider.info/thesamy/GalleriesTest/MainPage/Main.aspx (free hosting for test), I have 2 background images. The body that works in every browser and a content-wrapper that doesn't work in IE7, IE8.

I can't understand why, if the background img of the body shows, why it doesn't work in different areas on the page?

This is the HTML code of the area:

```
   <div id="Content-wrapper">

        <div id="GalleriesContent">
            <iframe scrolling="no" id="iframeBoxID" frameborder="0" class="iframeBoxClass" name="iframeBox"
                src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and here is the css:

```
#Content-wrapper
{
    /*background-image:url('../logo/blackBackGround2.png'); <-- tired that*/
      background-image:url(../logo/blackBackGround2.png);

}

#GalleriesContent
{
    background-color:transparent;
    clear: both;
}
.iframeBoxClass
{
     background-color:transparent;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever magical reason IE renders iframes with a white background and has to be told to explicitly render a transparent background in order for your div background to show. That behavior is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the fix is quite simple, simply add the following attribute to your iframe tag and it should fix the issue:

```
allowTransparency="true"

e.g.

<iframe allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```